# Attach an anonymous function to an "onclick" attribute of a link

Tags: javascript, onclick, anonymous-function

On various pages of a website I generate via JavaScript different click handlers attached to links in the `innerHTML` of an specific page element. I do it with a uitilty function like this:

```
function addClickLink(detail, detailHandler) {
    element.innerHTML = `Info about <a href="#" onclick="${detailHandler.name}(); return false;">${detail}</a>`
}
```

Calling `addClickLinkworks` works when `detailHandler` is a defined function like

```
function heliumHandler () { ... }


addClickLinkworks("Helium", heliumHandler)
```

but not when I call `addClickLinkworks` with an anonymous function:

```
addClickLinkworks("Helium", function() { ... })
```

How can I write the `"onclick"` string for anonymous functions?

Comment: I don't understand - why are you not just setting the element's onclick handler via javascript directly?

Comment: @AndrewParks Because I don't want the link on the whole element, but rather on a portion of the text only. I have adjusted the sample code to reflect this.

Comment: Did Nick's answer not suit your needs? If not, please specify why.

Comment: @AndrewParks Nick's answer is prefect. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the stringified version of the function, and then call it using `(<stringified function source)()` so that the `onclick` treats it as a function expression (rather than a statement):

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element");
function addClickLink(detail, detailHandler) {
  element.innerHTML = `Info about <a href="#" onclick="(${detailHandler})(); return false;">${detail}</a>`;
}

// This works:
//function heliumHandler() { console.log('function declaration); }
//addClickLink("Helium", heliumHandler)

// And so does this:
addClickLink("Helium", function() { console.log('function expression'); })
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

However, I wouldn't suggest this, as it can fail for native functions for example, and won't work correctly for bound functions. Rather than doing that, I would recommend that you create a HTML element and add your listener to that using `.addEventListener()`:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element");
function addClickLink(detail, detailHandler) {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const textNode = document.createTextNode("Info about ");
  
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.innerText = detail;
  anchor.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // similar to return false in your previous `onclick`
    detailHandler();
  });
  
  fragment.appendChild(textNode);
  fragment.appendChild(anchor);
  element.replaceChildren(fragment);
}

// This works:
// function heliumHandler() { console.log('function declaration); }
// addClickLink("Helium", heliumHandler)

// And so does this:
addClickLink("Helium", function() { console.log('function expression'); })
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: Totally can see that the second approach is safer. Thanks for both!